# How do I use ImageDataGenerator to do fixed transformations?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying perform 10-crop test time augmentation with ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory. The arguments in the base function performs random augmentations not fixed ones.

So I looked into using the apply_transform method from ImageDataGenerator. However, it takes x, and the transformation arguments. How do I connect this with flow_from_directory?

Answer (score 0):

Using [apply_transform](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#apply_transform) method, we can apply any desired transformations to an image.

```
apply_transform(x, transform_parameters)
```

Applies a transformation to x (3D tensor, single image) according to the transform parameters.

The `transform_parameters` is a dictionary specifying the set of transformations to be applied. Currently, the following transformations are available

```
- `'theta'`: Float. Rotation angle in degrees.
- `'tx'`: Float. Shift in the x direction.
- `'ty'`: Float. Shift in the y direction.
- `'shear'`: Float. Shear angle in degrees.
- `'zx'`: Float. Zoom in the x direction.
- `'zy'`: Float. Zoom in the y direction.
- `'flip_horizontal'`: Boolean. Horizontal flip.
- `'flip_vertical'`: Boolean. Vertical flip.
- `'channel_shift_intensity'`: Float. Channel shift intensity.
- `'brightness'`: Float. Brightness shift intensity.
```

Because `apply_transform` is a method inside the `ImageDataGenerator` class. so, first we have to create the instance of this class and then apply this method as below

```
from tf.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, load_img, img_to_array
img = load_img('/content/bird.jpg')
img = img_to_array(img)
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
rotate = datagen.apply_transform(x=img, transform_parameters={'theta':30, 'brightness':0.6, 'zx':0.9, 'zy':0.8})
```

For more information please refer this [blog](https://theailearner.com/2019/07/06/imagedatagenerator-apply_transform-method/).