# How can solve random_rotation error in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, rotation

I have some image which each of them has [128, 128, 60] size. I want use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_rotation` function to do some augmentation on them.

for random rotate I have  this function:

```py
def augment_rotate_tf(x):
    x = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_rotation(x,
                                                      50, 
                                                      row_axis=0,
                                                      col_axis=1,
                                                      channel_axis=2)

    return x
```

When I pass and numpy array to this function it work correctly, but when I use this in the tensorflow graph it arrise this error:

```
AttributeError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-99-790177542fdb>:15 augmentation  *
        img = tf.cond(cond, lambda: augment_rotate_tf_(img), lambda:  img)
    <ipython-input-124-28f8f87fa48b>:4 augment_rotate_tf_  *
        x = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_rotation(x,
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\affine_transformations.py:56 random_rotation  *
        x = apply_affine_transform(x, theta=theta, channel_axis=channel_axis,
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\affine_transformations.py:323 apply_affine_transform  *
        x = np.rollaxis(x, channel_axis, 0)
    <__array_function__ internals>:5 rollaxis  **
        
    C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\tf2.3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py:1259 rollaxis
        n = a.ndim

    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

How can solve this problem?

Comment: What version of Tensorflow are you using? Also why do your images have 60 channels?

Comment: I use 2.3. I want work on the ct images.

Comment: Could you try upgrading Tensorflow using `pip install tensorflow==2.4.1`? Or if that does not work try using [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class) to augment the image.

Comment: They aren't worked. Is there any way use  tensrflow for rotation not keras?

Comment: Did you tried using [apply_transform](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#apply_transform) method ? we can apply any desired transformations to an image. You can try with `apply_transform(x=img,transform_parameters={'theta':50})`, where theta is rotation angle in degrees. For more details you can refer [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64248138/14290681). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found an elegant hack of [knuckles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/767314/knuckles) here [A possible workaround is to incorporate the layers into the input pipeline.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63302446/colabtpu-not-supporting-tf-2-3-0-tf-keras-layers-experimental-preprocessing):

```py
random_rotator=tf.keras.layer.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(factor=0.055, fill_mode='constant',fill_value=0.)
<....>
ds= ds.batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
ds = ds.map(lambda d,l: (random_rotator.call(d,training=True), l), num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
```

This is my using of the hack. It works if you apply batching before, due the input wants the rank=4 where the first dimension is a batch size > 0